# Using result of ProjectWorldToScreen for DeprojectScreenToWorld does not produce initial input data

Tags: unreal-4, unreal

I am using this logic to project a point in world space into screen space.

```
const FVector Location = FVector(1, 2, 3);

FIntRect Rect;
Rect.Max.X = ViewportSize.X;
Rect.Max.Y = ViewportSize.Y;
FVector2D CurrentScreenSpaceCoords;

const FMatrix ViewProjectionMatrix = SceneView->ViewMatrices.GetViewProjectionMatrix();
SceneView->ProjectWorldToScreen(Location, Rect, ViewProjectionMatrix, CurrentScreenSpaceCoords);
```

I am using this code to get the initial value back

```
FMatrix const InvViewProjMatrix = ViewProjectionMatrix.Inverse();
FVector WorldPosition;
FVector WorldDirection;
FSceneView::DeprojectScreenToWorld(CurrentScreenSpaceCoords, Rect, InvViewProjMatrix, WorldPosition, WorldDirection);
```

However the result of DeprojectScreenToWorld does not produce the initial input (Location).
Instead of giving me the expected vector of [1, 2, ***whatever***], it gives me X = [69.8139954,3840.00073, 250.49826]

Edit:
I am interested in X,Y. I don't need Z.

Somebody knows:

1. Why this happens?
2. How to get the initial value back from it

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you expect to reconstruct a vector with three degrees of freedom (x, y, z) from an intermediate with only two degrees of freedom (x, y)? How should `DeprojectScreenToWorld` know what depth you want along the infinite 3D ray through that 2D point in the viewport?

Comment: Well it would be nice, if it could give me at least X,Y

Comment: You already have X, Y on the screen. Which X, Y that corresponds to in your world depends on the Z information, which you have discarded. What you are trying to do *cannot* work, in the sense of being mathematically impossible. To get the same output as you put in, you *must* preserve some depth or distance information to use in reconstructing the 3D point.